# Trigger Autocomplete Event When Clicking On a Button

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How can I trigger the `autocomplete` event of any textbox when I click on a button?

I've tried a lots of things, but so far nothing has worked.

```
$('.button').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.searchtxt').focus();

    $("#auto").autocomplete({                  
        source:'get_stud.php',          
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            getid(ui.item.value, this);
        }
    });

    $('#auto').focus();
});
```

Comment: does the autocomplete work if you take it out of the click function? Also why focus on `.searchtxt` when you just switch the focus?

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1yxf47b1/3/.  Also when you say any textbox, you have only targeted the textbox with an id of `auto`

Answer (score 0):

[autocomplete/#method-search](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search)

I find a method for this question,and it works.
using this method:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "search", "" );
```

put your keyword in the second params,try it.

Answer (score -1):

instead of

$('.button').on("click",function(e) {

use

$( ".button" ).click(function() {

Comment: `.click()` is syntactic sugar for `.on('click')` – this won’t fix the issue.